# How to convert part of a string that includes underscores to brackets in logstash with gsub

Tags: regex, ruby, logstash, gsub, logstash-filter

I want to convert, for e.g.
Hello_1_.Bye
to
Hello[1].Bye
Note that [1], i.e., within brackets contain only digits

I started with something like this that didn't work..

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => ["String", "*_\D_.*", "*[\D].*"] //Note that String here could be Hello_1_.Bye, Hello_2_.Bye etc.
  }
 }
```

but getting this error

```
:exception=>#<RegexpError: target of repeat operator is not specified: /*_\D_*/>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: You could use `"Hello_12_.Bye".sub(/_(\d+)_/) { "[#{$1}]" } #=> "Hello[12].Bye"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `gsub` is a [*setting*](https://elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html) in Logstash configuration file jargon. In this particular case, it is [the `gsub` setting](https://elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) of the `mutate` *filter module*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this version:

```rb
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => ["Hello_1_.Bye", "([^_]+)_(\d+)_(\.\w+)", "\1[\2]\3"]
  }
}
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eegHiM/1) showing that the replacement is working.