# how to convert part of a string that includes brackets to underscores in logstash

Tags: regex, ruby, filter, logstash, gsub

Referring to this [How to convert part of a string that includes underscores to brackets in logstash with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409555/how-to-convert-part-of-a-string-that-includes-underscores-to-brackets-in-logstas)

- what would be the reverse..

Input

```
Hello[1].Bye
```

Output

```
Hello_1_.Bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that using [mutate+gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) ...

```
mutate { gsub => [ "someField", "[\[\]]", "_" ] }
```

The question is currently tagged as though it wants a solution using a ruby filter, but I cannot see any reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
a="Hello[1].Bye"
```

Code

```
p a.gsub(/([^\[]*)\[(.*)\]\.(.*)/,'\1_\2_.\3')
```

Output

```
"Hello_1_.Bye"
```